# Calculate the data in the every row simultaneously

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php code here which get the data in database and display it in php, it will create a textbox in every row and column, what I want is in every textbox that I will change in every row the last row in table should be sum up. Is there a way to do it?and how? Thank you.

```
<?php
            include('../connect.php');
            //$listsubid=$_GET['listsubid'];
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studsubject WHERE listsubid='$listsubid'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo '<tr class="record">';
                    //echo '<td  style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7">'.$row['fname'].' '.$row['mname'].' '.$row['lname'].'</td>';
                    $sidnumber = $row['sidnumber'];

                    echo '<td><div align="left">'.$sidnumber.'&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</div></td>';
                    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE idnumber = '$sidnumber'");
                    while($row1 =mysql_fetch_array($result1))
                        {
                        echo '<td><div align = "left">'.$row1['lname'].' '.$row1['fname'].' '.$row1['mname'].'</div></td>';
                        echo '<input type = "text" name ="grade_id[]" value = '.$row['grade_id'].'>';
                        $grade_id = $row['grade_id'];
                            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prelim WHERE prelim_id = '$grade_id'");
                            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
                            {
                        echo '<td><input type="text" size= "2" maxlength = "3" name="att1[]" value = '.$row2['att1'].'></td>';
                        echo '<td><input type="text" size= "2" maxlength = "3" name="att2[]" value = '.$row2['att2'].'></td>';
                        echo '<td><input type="text" size= "2" maxlength = "3" name="att3[]" value = '.$row2['att3'].'></td>';
                        echo '<td><input type="text" size= "2" maxlength = "3" name="att4[]" value = '.$row2['att4'].'></td>'; } ?>
```

Comment: Using PHP, no.  If you want changes to the values in the inputs to produce effects on the page you'll likely need JavaScript.

Comment: can you show me some code?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use JavaScript. Is it possible to do it in PHP? Sure, but you will want to add an "Update" button that, when pressed, will not only sum the values but re-render the whole page with both the sum and the original values. I would strongly recommend not doing this, however.

If you use JavaScript, it's as simple as something like this:

```
var sum = document.getElementsByName("att").reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
document.getElementByID('totalTextBox').value = sum;
```

Just use `name="att"` for you text boxes instead of what you have.

Comment: how can I do this in javascript? I know i need to use a for loop here,  but can you give me some code? Thank you.

Comment: how can I get the value of "a" and "b", because the data in textbox is  in Array .

Comment: The code will work as it is as long as `textBoxValues` has your array of values. See the docs for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Try something like what I just added to my answer.

Comment: I want it to be like this att4=att1+att2+att3.

Comment: I want it to be like this att4=att1+att2+att3.

I currently reading the link you've shared, but still I can't get any idea. As you can see in my code it will create a row depend on how many data they get in my database. This code is for saving the attendance of student, first it wil display the list of student with those textbox, then now I need to input the record. And one last thing how can I trigger the function in javascript? do you think is is good if I trigger it in textbox? sorry for so many question :) .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, but for it to happen as the user changes it you will need to use javascript.

If you want your database to update as the user makes changes, you will need to watch each input field using something like jquery. If that field changes you can then make a post request to the server. This will require you to have a place to make a post, get, or put request.

The summing will also need to be done with javascript. You will need to watch each input field. If the user makes a change to one of the fields you will need to take that value, sum it with the rest of the row and then update the total.

You can do this with php as well but it will not happen as the user inputs new values. They will need to have a submit button, and after submission the user will be presented the update view.

Comment: yeah I think using php code is not good, because I can't see the changes whenever I input data in textbox, I think javascript is the best way, but Im a dummy in javascript, I know I need to use a For Loop there, but can you show me some code ?